# What is the default value of size in org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable?10 or 20?

Tags: spring

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mA3B.png)
I don't send the parameter of Pageable.I would like to use the default value.

[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5jV4.png)
I find that size is 20 while I debug.But the size is 10 defined in the

PageableDefault.Is it in conflict？

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default page size of Pagable is 20.

The API doc is here

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html#DEFAULT_MAX_PAGE_SIZE

Here you can see the default page size

```
static final Pageable DEFAULT_PAGE_REQUEST = new PageRequest(0, 20);
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for that and couldn't find it.  It was killing me not knowing where that 20 came from.